# Operational amplifier output voltage calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: opamp]

This problem asks for \$ v_O \$ in terms of circuit problems.

I solved the problem. But my solution has

\$ \large v_O = -R_4 (I_1 + \frac {V_1}{R_2} + \frac {V_2}{R_3}) \$

\$ I_1 \$ term as you'd see.

But according to solution manual it is like that.

[image: solution]

I wonder whether my solution is correct.

Comment: Try to use a superposition principle and you should be able to see why I1 don't influence the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks. If we apply superposition V1 would be short circuit. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, exactly. V1 will "sink" all I1 current.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put across V1, it will not affect the output voltage.  It's an ideal source so the voltage across it is independent of what it's attached to.  The exception is another ideal voltage source of a different voltage.  In that case the result is undefined or maybe the universe collapses into a tennis ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets do the superposition method from Helmholtz:

For only \$I_1\$, the circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDWPoo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The short-circuit, which replaces source \$V_1\$, short-circuits \$I_1\$. 
If you also assume that the OpAmp is ideal, the output voltage is zero.

For only \$V_1\$, the circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cztW.png)</sup>

Again, as we have an ideal OpAmp, \$V_{R3}\$ and \$V_{R1} is zero.

Therefore:

\$ V_1=V_{R2} \$

\$I_{R2} = \frac{V_1}{R_2} = I_{R4}\$

\$V_{out}=-V_{R4}=-R_4 \cdot I_{R4} = -V_1 \cdot \frac{R_4}{R_2}\$

For only \$V_2\$, the circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTLnKQ.png)</sup>

As we have an ideal OpAmp again, the voltage between "-" and "+" is zero and therefore:

\$ V_2 + V_{R3} = 0\$

\$V_{R2} = 0 \$ and thus \$I_{R2} = 0\$

\$I_{R3}=I_{R4}=\frac{V_2}{R_3}\$

\$V_{out}=-V_{R4}=-R_4\cdot I_{R4}=-V_2 \cdot \frac{R_4}{R_3}\$

Adding the results for \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ together, we get the final result:

\$ V_{out}=-V_1 \cdot \frac{R_4}{R_2} -V_2 \frac{R_4}{R_3}\$

I hope I could help you. If you still have questions, feel free to write a comment.

Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

\$I_1\$ should have nothing to do with it.  Ohms law directly tells you the current through \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$.  Therefore, you know the current through \$R_4\$ and thus, the output voltage.